# Freya very sluggish after plugging in monitor to laptop

Tags: display

I have two laptops and when I either install elementary OS Freya or run it off a USB. Every time I connect a monitor to the laptop the system responds very sluggishly. For eg: When I click on any of the dock icons it takes a good 12 seconds to respond. This is the case with all icons in fact after I connect the external monitor.

I have connected two different monitors to two different laptops and experiencing the same issue. I have also re-downloaded elementary OS Freya and done a update and an upgrade with no resolution yet.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: We kind of need more information about your laptop - What GPU is it using, for example?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think that would be necessary considering it's happening on two separate laptops with two completely different monitors however I can and will provide you with the information you need when I get to my laptop later on today. Please also let me know any other information you might find helpful so I can get all the information at once to minimize the need to go back and forth unnecessarily. Thanks for your prompt response, and I will have the info shortly.

Comment: Sounds like your graphics card or graphics driver can't handle the amount of extra pixels. Make sure you are using the best driver for your card which will probably be the one made by the manufacturer. See if anything is maxing out your CPU with the `top` command.

Comment: I occasionally get this problem due to gala, the window manager. Does running gala --replace (press alt+f2, type gala --replace, and press enter) work for you?

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks I will try that. @embik - Here is the GPU information - Graphics Processor PCI Express - Intel GMA 950 - PROCESSOR / CHIPSET
Full specs - http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-business-notebook-nx6320-15-core-duo-t2300-win-xp-pro-512-mb-ram-80-gb-hdd/specs/ - Only difference is mine has 3GB of RAM

Comment: By the way - Windows 7, 8 and XP and other Linux O/S's have no problem with the extra monitor eg: CentoOS Desktop 6x

Comment: If you want to test it manually, you could try (taking 1920x1080 and use mini display port, DP1, as an example) `#!/bin/bash

cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP1 1920x1080_60.00#!/bin/bash

cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP1 1920x1080_60.00`

Comment: @Life - apologise but I'm not that much of a Linux guru, your suggestion kinda went right over my head except for what I think is your asking me to try it from another port with a different resolution? Do I type this command into the terminal? Where shall I plug the monitor into? Same SVGA?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. Does the **sluggish respond** also happen in the console mode (`ctrl+alt+1`)? Try typing some basic commands like `ls` to see the effect. BTW, (`ctrl+alt+7`) to go back to GUI mode.

Comment: @Life - Apologies for the delay, I have been working and not been able to respond as quick as I would like to have. Ok, thanks to some assistance from Stack Exchange. I think we are getting closer to a resolution. I ran "top" on the affected laptop - "gala" is running at 100% CPU utilization. This is on the HP6320. I then ran it on my newer HP Probook and although I previously thought it was doing it on that laptop as well, it's clear that it's not affecting the new Probook as CPU utilization is only at about 1 or 2 % and gala is not to be seen.

Comment: @Life - taking this into consideration - It's apparent that I need to get on to the ubuntu forums for a fix? I'm unsure where to go for a fix. I'll do a bit of scouting around to see if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check these points:

- OS dependent?

  - From the system monitor, is the OS working slowly after it is plugged into the current monitor?
- Hardware

  - Try to switch a monitor to see if it happens.
- Software

  - Try to use different drivers provided in
    Ubuntu/elementary OS repositories.
- User Settings

  - Does the graphics refresh normally?
  - Is the frequency the right one? Try to switch it.

Not sure whether it is an elementary OS bug or not. Anyway, my Dell
computer works really fine when working with an external
monitor.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned in my previous post. It seems to be an issue with "gala window manager" on this specific laptop.

The moment I connect a external monitor to this laptop, and I connected two different monitors, a Benq and a HP, straight away "gala window manager" goes to over 100% CPU utilization.

This does not occur with my newer laptop which I believe points investigation into the GPU driver and trolling gala window managers site for a fix. If I do come across a fix I will post it, meantime, I will also use it on a desktop this coming weekend with the same monitors and update.

Comment: Perhaps should let Elementary Team know this.